# Build Tab missing in pyqtdeploy

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, pyqtdeploy

I'm trying to deploy my PyQt5 application using pyqtdeploy. The pyqtdeploy GUI shows up, but there is no tab for Build. I have tried in different computers, but the Build tab is still not there. What is the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you must be using pyqtdeploy version 2.x, which differs in some important ways from pyqtdeploy 1.x. Unfortunately, the documentation currently shown [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/pyqtdeploy/) has not been updated, and refers to version 1.3.2.

In the meantime, I suggest you download the [source code](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyqtdeploy) and open up *docs/html/index.html*, so you can read the proper documentation for version 2.x.

I will quote here the section which deals with the specific problem regarding the Build Tab:

> *Differences from Version 1*
>
> There have been a number of changes to pyqtdeploy since v1. Most of
>   these changes are related to the supporting tools rather than the GUI.
>   Project files created for v1 are automatically updated by later
>   versions.
>
> [...]
>
> **The pyqtdeploycli program has been removed. The build functionality
>   has been replaced by the new pyqtdeploy-build program**.
>
> **The Build tab of the pyqtdeploy GUI has been removed. The sole purpose
>   of the GUI is now to create and modify a project file**.
>
> [...]

Comment: Thank you, ekhumoro. I just read the documentation and it says the Build tab has been removed in the latest version. But I still can't get it to work. The documentation is not easy to understand with my limited knowledge. Do you know a link to a good toturial on how to use pyqtdeploy? I've been googling all night and still can't find one.

Comment: @NuhYamin. The documentation is quite extensive and is as good as you are going to get. The source code also contains a demo, which should help a lot in getting a basic example to work.

Comment: The documentation of pyqtdeploy has been updated for version 2! However I am still struggling to learn how to use it...:\